# Make div take up all width and height after transform: rotate(90deg)

Tags: html, css

I have a battleship game which takes up 100% width and 100% height of body (e.g fullscreen), this game has a media query: when screen width < 420px then the game should be rotated by 90degree (to landscape mode) and after rotation it should also take up the entire viewport, but after rotation the width of the game is 100% of viewport (height in landscape mode) and height only around 50% of viewport (width in landscape mode). So how can I make the game to take up all viewport in landscape mode?

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="game"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkBackground);
    font-family: var(--fontFamily);
}

#game{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
    #game{
        height: 100vw;
        width: 100vh;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--darkBackground);
    font-family: var(--fontFamily);
}

#game{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
    #game{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="game">Test</div>
</body>


</html>
```